# Batch script for generating email address with date and time

Tags: email, batch, generator

I want to create a batch script that outputs an email address based on the date/time the script is run, and puts it in the clipboard. For example, if I run it, an email address is generated like this
support-08-30-22-09-19-00@servertest.com
I use this for testing so that I can then search error logs with a more exact time, making it easier to narrow down the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.
Normally, I don't write scripts for people on this site (SU is not a free script writing service) but this one was a two liner with no logic so I did it anyway.

```bat
@echo off

:: First, I am using powershell to get the date just like requested.
:: It gives us total control over the format.
for /f %%a in ('powershell -Command "Get-Date -format MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss"') do set email_addr=support-%%a@servertest.com

:: Now, put our value into the clipboard
echo %email_addr%|clip
```

Good luck.